# Batch reboot with message delay

Tags: batch-file

I see there are some topics related to my question but there is something missing, I need to create a batch that reboots the computer and send a pop; I have this:

```
@echo off
cd c:\windows\system32
shutdown -r -t 600 -c "Your machine you need to reboot in 5 minutes." -f 
exit
```

However I need something more, I need a reminder of 2 minutes before the computer reboots, and there is a way that the user can stop or propose a new time before the computer restart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like that :

```dos
@echo off
shutdown -r -t 600 -c "Your machine you need to reboot in 5 minutes." -f 
Call :AskQuestion
exit
::***********************************************************************
:AskQuestion
(
    echo    Set Ws = CreateObject("wscript.shell"^)
    echo    wscript.sleep 180000
    echo    Answ = MsgBox("Did you want to cancel the scheduled reboot of your the computer ?"_
    echo ,VbYesNo+VbQuestion,"Did you want to cancel the scheduled reboot of your the computer ?"^)
    echo    If Answ = VbYes then 
    echo        Return = Ws.Run("cmd /c Shutdown -a",0,True^)
    echo    Else
    echo        wscript.Quit(1^)
    echo    End If
)>"%tmp%\%~n0.vbs"
Start "" "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off
shutdown -r -t 300 -c "Your machine you need to reboot in 5 minutes."  
Echo Press any key to cancel
timeout /t 180
Echo 2 mins to go
timeout /t 9999
shutdown /a
```

For general help. Type `Help` in the command prompt. For each command listed type `help <command>` (eg `help dir`) or `<command> /?` (eg `dir /?`).